# Android toolbar not responding in some OS versions

Tags: android, android-studio, listener

I've written an application which utilizes some templates supplied by Android Studio.  When I set the lowest OS to target in Android Studio, I selected API 15.  When I run the app on 4.4.2 or 4.0.4, the toolbar (three dots) does not respond, and has nothing in the log.

[image: not responding in older OS versions]

Newer OS's (5.1) work ok.

What I've done is to use Android Studio to create a new project (similar to the way I created the project originally).  But when I try those little sample project on the old OS's, the toolbar responds.

How should I go about debugging this?  It seems that there's some under the covers stuff here, and I'm not sure how to see what's happening (or actually, not happening).  So this question is about how one diagnoses problems that are happening in code outside of the set of code that the developer actually constructed by-hand.

Comment: With the release of Android 5.0 and material design, Android has updated the AppCompat support libraries so that we can use Toolbars on devices running API Level 7 and up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use app compact support library toolbar.

```
 Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Comment: Saeed, I didn't check the toolbar idea, but I'll green check this since there is likely no more activity on this thread. My original problem was due to using a non-appcompat version of a ScrollView. Thanks for bringing this question to view again.